# a way to list elements by name, html, php

Tags: php, mysql, html, inventory

I'm creating a small car dealership website, and on my inventory page I need to be able to list all the cars I have , and a way to narrow them down.

Whats the best what to achieve this? The simpler way the better even if i need to do abit more work.

I thought each car entry has to be an element with specific name and than I would use the navigation to list the element by selected name. But im not sure where to start with this. Cant seem to find any good tutorial. However been what it is i feel like there should be tons of solution for my problem..

Basically each element needs to have title , description and a picture. Please point me in the right direction, a database perhaps? I could do abit of mysql but nothing pass the beginner levels

Comment: Try this: http://www.google.co.nz/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=PHP,+Mysql+Tutorial&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=fbKgT5ScHKWeiAfPwcHZBA

Comment: Read. The only requirement is that most of my posts aren't promotion, and, that I clearly show my affiliation with what I'm promoting. I did both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i will suggest you to use any shopping cart or any e-commerce solution which will be available free of cost and you can make tweaks when you get the knowledge about these stuff.

i will suggest you to use "Wordpress + WP-E-Commerce"  you just need to install the wordpress, you can create your own theme or can find a good theme while wp-ecommerce is also having free version which will solve your all problems you stated above.

feel free to ask me if you have any other question

Comment: Thank you, i'm trying to avoid databases and such, it shouldnt be more than 20-30 entrees. But i guess its better to do it right